# How to distinguish numbered from unnumbered chapters?

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am writing a [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document and I'd like to customize the visual appearance of the chapter title with [Tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)<sup>1</sup>. This works so far, as shown by this MWE<sup>2</sup>:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\noindent\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node (bottomleft) at (0,0) {};
  \node (topright) at (\textwidth,\baselineskip) {};

  \draw[red] (bottomleft.center) -- (topright.center);

  \node at ($(bottomleft)!0.5!(topright)$) {\textbf{#1}};
  \node at (.1\textwidth, .5\baselineskip) {\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter*{Extra}

\lipsum[11-20]

\chapter{Last}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

This outputs the chapter name and chapter number at the beginning of each chapter in such a way that both pieces of information are embedded into the graphic.

Unfortunately (albeit unsurprisingly), the middle *unnumbered* chapter (`\chapter*`) reuses the number of the previous chapter. I would like to hide that number. Therefore, my question is:

**How can I find out whether or not the current chapter is numbered?** Is there any function that returns such a value, or a function that only prints its argument if the current chapter is numbered?

<sup>1</sup>: My actual graphic is quite a bit more complex and more appealing. The simple graphical chapter title in the MWE here are just for demonstration purposes.

<sup>2</sup>: Unlike my actual document, this MWE draws its contents from the [`lipsum` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).

Comment: I had a similar question in mind while adding front and back matter to my thesis (though for the page header) and ended up changing the definition of the header based on where I was in the document.  This was mainly for reasons of time.  I think you'd need to patch the definition of `\chapter` and/or `\chapter*` to set a value to the chapter number of blank.  Alternatively keep a count of the *previous* chapter number and compare that to the current reported value in your figure generating routine.  Just a couple of thoughts in case no better way appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is more or less how `memoir` builds chapter headings

**Numbered:**

```
 \chapterheadstart % vert space
 \printchaptername
 \chapternamenum % space between chapter name and num
 \printchapternum
 \afterchapternum % mid space
 \printchaptertitle{Title}
 \afterchaptertitle % space below
```

**Unnumbered:**

```
 \chapterheadstart % vert space
 \printchapternonum % empty by default
 \printchaptertitle{Title}
 \afterchaptertitle % space below
```

While building a chapter style, it is perfectly fine to ditch some of these macros and move functionality into others. Then for example `\printchapternonum` can be used to run a switch such that `\printerchaptertitle` know it is being used in an unnumbered context.

So using Christians solution with a build in test inside `\printchaptertitle`, it is enough for use to add

```
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\isstarredchaptertrue}
```

and the code will work for both numbered and unnumbered chapters.

For completness, here is Christians code slightly modified without the need for patching.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\newif\ifisstarredchapter
% false by default
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (bottomleft) at (0,0) {};
  \node (topright) at (\textwidth,\baselineskip) {};
  \draw[red] (bottomleft) -- (topright);
  \node at ($(bottomleft)!0.5!(topright)$) {\textbf{#1}};
  \ifisstarredchapter
  \else
  \node at (.1\textwidth, .5\baselineskip) {\thechapter};
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\isstarredchaptertrue}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter*{Extra}

\lipsum[11-20]

\chapter{Last}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works! By the way, in addition to chapters, I'm meanwhile trying to achieve the [same thing for parts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270634/how-to-distinguish-numbered-from-unnumbered-parts), where the analogous solution does not seem to be available - there is no such thing as `\printpartnonum`, it seems (?)

Comment: No, that is only available for chapters. In this case you will probable have to patch `\@part` and `\@spart`

Comment: Thanks, that helped developed a [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270769/18853).

Answer (score 3):

This solution hooks into the `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` commands, being responsible for the unstarred and the starred chapter packages. It toggles a `\ifstarredchapter` conditional correspondingly which is then used in the `tikzpicture` environment in order to decide whether the chapter number should be printed or not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\newif\ifisstarredchapter

\isstarredchapterfalse

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (bottomleft) at (0,0) {};
  \node (topright) at (\textwidth,\baselineskip) {};
  \draw[red] (bottomleft) -- (topright);
  \node at ($(bottomleft)!0.5!(topright)$) {\textbf{#1}};
  \ifisstarredchapter
  \else
  \node at (.1\textwidth, .5\baselineskip) {\thechapter};
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \chapterheadstart%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
}{%
  \isstarredchapterfalse%  No, this is not a starred chapter
  \chapterheadstart%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
}{\typeout{success}}{}

\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{%
  \chapterheadstart%
}{%  
  \isstarredchaptertrue% Yes, this is starred chapter. 
  \chapterheadstart%
}{\typeout{Success}}{}



\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter*{Extra}

\lipsum[11-20]

\chapter{Last}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the patching really necessary? ``\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\isstarredchaptertrue\chapterheadstart}`` seems to do the same thing in this case.

Comment: @daleif: I don't know. I am no `memoir` expert. Sometimes I refrain from `\renewcommand`

Comment: This works in my example document, but in my actual document, it breaks compilation with the error `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty:1543: LaTeX / error: "kernel/command-already-defined" / ! Control sequence \BooleanFalse already defined.`

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Well, what should I do then? I don't know your real document

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sure, I'm just pointing out that the solution is not yet compatible with all contexts (so other possible visitors know). As long as I don't know what's the difference between 200+ pages document and my MWE, I cannot update my MWE or ask a new question, but I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Then try daleif's proposition above. I'll delete my answer then

Comment: I already did, and it works. If @daleif wrote an answer, I'd accept it, as his or her solution *seems* to be more robust right now. However, that does not mean that your solution does not have any advantages in different situations that I cannot think of now; upvoted for that and I suggest you also leave it alife.

Comment: I've added an answer based on Christians, but without patching. Also explained what is going on (for those not knowing about how `memoir` builds it chapters)