# How to distinguish numbered from unnumbered parts?

Tags: memoir, parts

This question is analogous to [my earlier recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270539/how-to-distinguish-numbered-from-unnumbered-chapters). The other questions refers to **chapters**, this one refers to **parts**. The solution for chapters does not seem to work for parts.

---

I am writing a [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document and I'd like to customize the visual appearance of the part title with [Tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)<sup>1</sup>. This works so far, as shown by this MWE<sup>2</sup>:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\noindent\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node (bottomleft) at (0,0) {};
  \node (topright) at (\textwidth,\baselineskip) {};

  \draw[red] (bottomleft.center) -- (topright.center);

  \node at ($(bottomleft)!0.5!(topright)$) {\textbf{#1}};

  \node at (.1\textwidth, .5\baselineskip) {\thepart};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\part{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\part*{Extra}

\lipsum[11-20]

\part{Last}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

This outputs the part name and part number at the beginning of each part in such a way that both pieces of information are embedded into the graphic.

Unfortunately (albeit unsurprisingly), the middle *unnumbered* part (`\part*`) reuses the number of the previous part. I would like to hide that number. Therefore, my question is:

**How can I find out whether or not the current part is numbered?** Is there any function that returns such a value, or a function that only prints its argument if the current part is numbered?

---

As I have already asked [the analogous question about chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270539/how-to-distinguish-numbered-from-unnumbered-chapters), I have first tried to apply the solution suggested for that question:

While numbered chapters invoke the `\printchapternum` command, unnumbered chapters will invoke the `\printchapternonum` command instead. Therefore, each of these commands can be replaced in a way to set a marker that can then be checked from within `\printchaptertitle`.

Unfortunately, while `\printpartnum` exists for parts, no analogous command `\printpartnonum` seems to exist. In the [`memoir` manual](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), there also is no analogous mention of unnumbered parts as there is about unnumbered chapters and `\printchapternonum`. Hence, the solution that works for chapters apparently will not work for parts.

---

<sup>1</sup>: My actual graphic is quite a bit more complex and more appealing. The simple graphical part title in the MWE here are just for demonstration purposes.

<sup>2</sup>: Unlike my actual document, this MWE draws its contents from the [`lipsum` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270539/how-to-distinguish-numbered-from-unnumbered-chapters#comment649893_270670) by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif), I could solve this by patching `\@spart`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifisstarredpart
\isstarredpartfalse

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\@oldspart}{\@spart}
\renewcommand{\@spart}[1]{\isstarredparttrue\@oldspart{#1}\isstarredpartfalse}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}%{\isstarredpartfalse}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\noindent\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\baselineskip);

  \node (bottomleft) at (0,0) {};
  \node (topright) at (\textwidth,\baselineskip) {};

  \draw[red] (bottomleft.center) -- (topright.center);

  \node at ($(bottomleft)!0.5!(topright)$) {\textbf{#1}};

  \ifisstarredpart
  \else
    \node at (.1\textwidth, .5\baselineskip) {\thepart};
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\part{First}

\lipsum[1-10]

\part*{Extra}

\lipsum[11-20]

\part{Last}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

For patching, I have used the [`letltxmacro` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro), as suggested in [an answer for another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/18853).

The patch than works so that before the original `\@spart` is evaluated, the flag for starred parts is set to `true`, and afterwards, it is set to `false` again.